# Pass javascript variable data as URL to controller in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii2

Is there any way i can send the 'data' of this javascript file attached to url so i can get it from controller.
js part

```
$urlView1 = Url::to('cdr/compare');
$script1 = <<< JS
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-compare', function(e) {

        var items=document.getElementsByName('checkbox1[]');
        var selectedItems="";
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            if(items[i].type=='checkbox' && items[i].checked==true){
                selectedItems+=","+items[i].value;
            }
        }
        //console.log("{$urlView1}")

        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=cdr/compare",
            type : 'post',
            data: 'items=' + selectedItems,
            success : function(data){
                console.log(data);

                //$('#view-comp').attr("src", $(this).attr('data-url'));
                //$('#ViewModal').modal({show:true})
                //var data = JSON.parse(data);
            },
        });
        $('#view-comp').attr("src", $(this).attr('data-url'));
        $('#ViewComp').modal({show:true})
        return false;            
});
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script1);
```

controller

```
public function actionCompare(){
        //$vafr=explode(',',$_GET['items']);
        $model = new CdrAllinone();
       $session = Yii::$app->session;
        $this->layout = 'popup';
        var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post("items"));
        exit;
```

checkbox data post with this button. it iterates over a loop

```
 <?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon pull-right glyphicon-transfer"></span>', ['#'], ['data-url' => Url::toRoute(['cdr/compare']), 'id' => 'btn-compare', 'title' => 'Compare']); ?>
```

And I'm okay for any checkbox method if works properly. please give some ideas.